Movie about kids(teens?) talking to an old-man ghost who looks like Yoda
I remember seeing a movie on VHS back in the 90's (the film itself looked like it could've been from any time in the 80's all the way to the early 90's), about a group of kids (possibly teenagers, or younger) interacting with the ghost of a very old man.  I only remember the following details:

The ghost reminded me heavily of Yoda, but Caucasian instead of green.
At one point, the kids ask the ghost about the afterlife, and he says that there are no faces there; all the living characters are unsettled by this.
The movie was English language, and I don't remember the characters having any non-American accents...though take that with a grain of salt.

Unfortunately, that's all I remember.  I was very young at the time, and the VHS was a duplicate, so I don't even know what the original case looked like.  
This has been bugging me for years, but I've never been able to narrow down the search results (including Yoda in the search terms just obliterates anything that isn't Star Wars related).

Thanks for the edit, Napoleon...I should've caught that in the preview.

Sounds like Roland Emmerich's Hollywood-Monster (AKA Ghost Chase) from 1987. From Wiki:

In an old Hollywood mansion, the spirit of a butler inhabits a grandfather clock. When two teenagers decide to use the mansion (which once belonged to one of the teen's grandfather) for a film, they encounter the spirit frightening away a burglar. The other teen builds a mechanical body for the spirit to possess when next he appears.

The body that the ghost inhabits is a small dummy that looks like Yoda with white hair (or, to be brutally honest, it's a total rip-off of ET). And at some point he informs one of the kids that he can't identify celebrities in the afterlife because there are no faces there. Here's the trailer:




That looks like it!  You have no idea how much that's been bugging me all these years.  I'm going to have to snag a copy and re-watch it as an adult to break the curse.

Well, it's on Youtube in 6 parts, if you absolutely must. ;)

No one made a copyright claim?  Truly shocking.
